# how to filter contacts in Android using a keyword

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, android-cursor

I am working on an application that returns a list of contacts based on keyword after calling an intent. The Keyword can be anything from name to phone number to address to company name.

I am not sure how to actually pass the keyword value to the intent that will launch the contact list. Could anyone please advise on how to achieve this?

I am rather desperate.

Thanks.

Comment: I would like some more detailed information anyone, please!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent.putExtra (String name, String value) to pass your activity the keyword you need to filter the contact list and use this in the SqlLite where clause in order to filter.

Comment: thanks blackbelt, please please show me some kind of code sample..really appreciate it